# Pandas Combine Multiple Specific Previous Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I wasn't 100% sure how to word the question title as its quite a specific thing I am asking. I have simplified the question into the core relevant components and made up some dataframes to demonstrate what I am after.

I have data of the form:

[image: original data]

I am trying to run some prediction algorithm on this data and want it in the form:

[image]

Where the stats of a player_id and game_id are taken as combinations of the previous n (n=2 in this example) game_ids stats of that player.

For example for player_id = 1 and game_id = 3 the stats are set to the sum of their corresponding values in game_id = 2 and game_id = 1. I also want players with missing game_id stats to be handled as all stats = 0 for the missing game_id (as in player_id = 2, game_id = 3 and 4).

I was thinking of creating a new dataset with rows for each player_id and each game_id combination as indexes (starting from game_id = n + 1 as you need at least n prior games number of stats) and then copying over values from the previous dataset using some sort of concatenation or join (taken from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) but I am unsure of the best way to do this with n rows needed to be concatenated based of the player_id and game_id.

Any help or suggestions is much appriated!

Comment: please provide a textual example of your dataframe, read [mcve]

Comment: see `groupby.rolling` + dropna at the end ... maybe `df.groupby('player_id').rolling(n+1).sum()` or similar

Comment: @ansev Thanks man im researching this now and it shows promise!